# How to get GFCC instead of MFCC in python?

Tags: python, audio, artificial-intelligence, mfcc, librosa

Today i'm using MFCC from librosa in python with the code below. It gives an array with dimension(40,40).

```
import librosa

sound_clip, s = librosa.load(filename.wav)
mfcc=librosa.feature.mfcc(sound_clip, n_mfcc=40, n_mels=60)
```

Is there a similiar way to extract the GFCC from another library? I do not find it in 
librosa.

For example essentia:

https://essentia.upf.edu/documentation/essentia_python_tutorial.html
https://essentia.upf.edu/documentation/reference/std_GFCC.html

```
import essentia
import essentia.standard

essentia.standard.GFCC

#Get array with dimension (40,40)
```

Answer (score 4):

I have been facing similar problems, therefore I wrote a small library called [spafe](https://pypi.org/project/spafe/), that simplifies features extractions from audio files. Among the supported features there is GFCC. The extraction can be done as in the following:

```
import scipy
from spafe.features.gfcc import gfcc

# read wav 
fs, sig = scipy.io.wavfile.read("test.wav")

# compute features
gfccs = gfcc(sig, fs=fs, num_ceps=13)
```

You can find a thorough example of GFCC extraction (as a jupyter-notebook) under [gfcc-features-example](https://github.com/SuperKogito/spafe/blob/master/examples/features_gfcc_example.ipynb).

The documentation of all the possible input variables and their significance are available under: [gfcc-docs](https://spafe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/gfcc.html).

**the gfcc implementation is done as in the following [paper](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-New-Algorithm-for-Auditory-Feature-Extraction-Xu-Lin/ec3daf2762d14a00efd1068137464e7d5ee43642#paper-header)**
[image]

Comment: how could I determine the output shape? I mean num_ceps can be computed by paramater num_ceps, but how to get the number of num_frames? Also, I noticed that the result of your function is the transpose of the result of librosa, is that right?

Comment: you can figure out the shape of your output matrix using `gfccs.shape`, this will return the  2d-output matrix shape `(m, n)`, where (m=number of frames , n=num_ceps). The number of frames can be computed from the input wave duration `= len(sig)/fs`, the fames length `win_len` and the frames overlap `win_hop`.

Comment: Hi SuperKogito, can you please tell me where to find gtcc features extraction code? Can I use gfcc instead of gtcc? Thanks

Comment: This is the code: https://github.com/SuperKogito/spafe/blob/master/spafe/features/gfcc.py Can you please rephrase the second question.